# Attribute not known during run time, but recognized during pdb debug

Tags: python, pdb

Check out the following piece of code.

I get a `UnboundLocalError: "local variable 'os' referenced before assignment"` error at the if statement.

I set a pdb trace right there, and I tried to check out the os module.

```
import os
import pdb

... 

pdb.set_trace()

if not os.path.exists(path_to_temp):
    os.makedirs(path_to_temp)
```

Here's my bizarre interaction in pdb:

```
(Pdb) os.path.exists(path_to_temp)
False
(Pdb)  not os.path.exists(path_to_temp)
True
(Pdb) os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
(Pdb) os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
(Pdb) n
UnboundLocalError: "local variable 'os' referenced before assignment"
```

I don't even...

**EDIT**: Omg, shame on me. I had a local `import os` somewhere after this if-statement too!!

Comment: Try adding a `print os` right before the `if`. See if that triggers the same behaviour.

Comment: That makes sense under python variable scoping rules, although it is in a sense a corner case.

Comment: I'm new to this.. How can I close this question? I don't really want to delete as someone else might benefit from this too. Also, I still find it strange that pdb did know `os`...

Comment: I guess pdb doesn't use normal variable resolution rules. There isn't a way to close the question yourself, unfortunately. Your best bet is to write up the solution as an answer, and then accept it.

Comment: Apparently I can't accept my own answer until 2 days from now... Thanks, btw.

Comment: There's some kind of time limit before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had a local `import os` after this if-statement, which was affecting the `os` attribute for the scope of that function.